# Is required an element if an attribute inside is required?

Tags: xml

I have the following xsd schemma:

```
...    
 - <xs:element name="Wire">
  - <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="Wire_Type" type="tWireType" use="required">
    </xs:complexType>
```

....

Is the element "wire" required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `<Wire>` element isn't required. However, if you do include a `<Wire>` element in your XLM document, then it MUST have the `Wire_Type` attribute:

```
<Wire />   // invalid
<Wire Wire_type="copper" /> // valid
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the `Wire` element is optional. The `Wire_Type` attribute is required on element `Wire`, if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

The element is not required because of its attribute's disposition.

However it can be required because of its `minOccurs` setting, which has a default of `1`.

See [XML Schema Part 0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints) for details.